# How to display the name of my Godfather on my page

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing one MLM system and i want to display the name of the Godfather on the space of her godson.

this is the stucture of the database:

```
Godfather: (id, name, email, pasword, cle, created_at);
godson: (id, idParrrain, idFileul, created-at);
```

**join :** Godfather.cle = godson.idParrrain**

Please help me with one sql request

```
$req = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Godfather INNER JOIN Godfather.cle = godson.idParrrain");

$result=$req>fetchAll();
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN godson ON Godfather.cle = godson.idParrrain` You have to specify which table you are joining to as well as which columns make the join

Comment: An exemple please. i don't undestand

Comment: That looks like an example to me.

Comment: Ok i didn't read well. I'm a francephone. 
so now i have this error:  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

Comment: did you add `SELECT * FROM Godfather` before the example. The full query would be `SELECT * FROM Godfather INNER JOIN godson ON Godfather.cle = godson.idParrrain`. You may optionally want to add a `WHERE` clause if you want to filter the results.

Comment: Thank>i dont have that eror anymore. 

but now my foreach is not good

foreach ($result as $results) {
    $name = $results['Godfather.name'];
    $email= $results['Godfather.email'];
                                                    }

Comment: Whn i do var_dump($result); I have array(0) { }